# Check box check event is not working in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have a checkbox as follows.

```
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsWeekendFlat, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

In my add details page this IsWeekendFlat is returning false even if I have checked this. But in my edit details page I am using the same, but there it is working properly.

Following is the model code.

```
  public bool IsWeekendFlat { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your question I believe is not clear, is the check box not checked by default for a new record. Or is it that during posting time the value is false even when checked?

Comment: Please elaborate a little bit more.

Comment: Question edited